# query to calculate the total salary for each month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, sum

I have a table with 4 fields as follows
[image]

I want an Sql query to calculate a total salary for each month, where the result will be as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want `group by` and `sum()`?

```
select sum(salary) salary, month
from mytable
group by month
```

Comment: what if we don't have month column? then what will be the query for it?